# SharePoint searching contents that match any of my keywords

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, search-center, query-rule

I am trying to configure my search center. The target is creating a search rule which will return documents that match any of keywords users type in. (Same functionality in advanced search, but I want to set up as default query rule for this search center...)

[image: Reference 1]

How do I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `IsDocument=1` to your query rule or result source?